# MYSQL/Laravel LIKE behaving unexpectedly

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have a bunch of mathematical tasks which I want to filter through a textbox.

For example: 
4*1 should return 4*1, 4*10, 4*11, ...
4*11 should return 4*11

To do that I wrote this piece of code:

```
$operator = DB::connection()->getPdo()->quote("{$operator}");
$operand2 = DB::connection()->getPdo()->quote("{$operand2}%");
DB::table('tasks')
        ->select(DB::raw('*'))
        ->whereRaw("operand1 = {$operand1} AND operator = {$operator} AND CAST(operand2 AS CHAR(50)) LIKE {$operand2}")
        ->get();
```

The results of this are pretty unexpected und unpredictable.
When I type 4*5 I get 4*{any operand}
When I type 4*12 I get 4*1, 4*10, 4*11, 4*12

**UPDATE/SOLUTION**
It turned out that it didn't have anything to with MySQL or Laravel. It was an error in JS. I used the keypress event instead of keyup. This way always the last typed digit was lost.

Comment: If you dd("operand1 = {$operand1} AND operator = {$operator} AND CAST(operand2 AS CHAR(50)) LIKE {$operand2}"), what do you get?

Comment: @MattJameson It's exactly one digit less than entered at the second operand. 
When I enter 1*4 it's 'operand1 = 1 AND operator = '*' AND CAST(operand2 AS CHAR(50)) LIKE '%'' for 1*12 it's 'operand1 = 1 AND operator = '*' AND CAST(operand2 AS CHAR(50)) LIKE '1%''

Comment: thats why- its because its one digit less and your where clause will pick that up